# Original domain (which is 301 redirected) meta description doesn't update

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, meta-description

I have a domain name `example.com` which I 301 redirected to `www.example.com`.

Problem is when I search for the website on Google, it shows the `.com` rather than the `www`. So the `.com` meta description shows, and since there is nothing on it, it has GoDaddy stuff written all over it.

I've re-crawled both sites using Google Webmaster Tools but still no luck.

Anyone have any idea on how this can be updated? Or will I just have to be patient?

Comment: When did you apply the 301 redirect?

Comment: Why don't you CNAME redirect instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you recently apply the 301 redirect, you need to be patient with Google; it takes time to update your meta description in the SERPs.

Pay attention of having a relevant meta description for the `www` version of your site and you would see it updated in the SERPs after the next crawling phases of your page by Googlebot.

P.S.: no matter your web host.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Would you think it would take 1 week or longer?

Comment: It can take a day, it can take a week, it can take a month to do such updates. Each site is different, for example news sites get updated faster than sites about memorials, CNN gets updated faster than a local news company etc... So many factors.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your help Zistoloen and Bybe.